# How do I correctly write a Concept file in Gauge.IO?

Tags: gauge, getgauge

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I am currently working on a Test Automation project with the relatively new tool Gauge (https://github.com/getgauge). I am trying to create a .cpt (Concept) file that specifies a certain step, consisting of other steps.

However, as I run the tests that use the concept in Visual Studio, I get an error saying:

```
line no. 2, Step is not defined inside a concept heading
```

The code inside said concept file is as follows:

```
# Es lauft
* Es lauft jetzt
```

This is of course just test code, but it is nonetheless not working, even though I styled the document as described in the official docs.

Has someone got this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The possible error will be :
1) Scenario test and two dotted lines should exists for starting any feature file.

2) Scenario will start by only one dotted line.

In your case it should be :

```
 Es lauft(starting feature file)
=====================



EsLauft(heading of your scenario)
----------------
* Es lauft jetzt
```

Please check the below working feature file.

```
Scenario tests
=====================
Created by mayank on 17/8/15

This is an executable specification file which follows markdown syntax.
Every heading in this file denotes a scenario. Every bulleted point denotes a step.
These are context steps

 table: /home/mayank/abc.csv


This is a heading
----------------
* Set default as "API"
* I made Request as <request>
* I check Response as <response>
* Set
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a concept file with following syntax for each concept.

```
# Register Gemunu
* Fill Contact Information section
    |FirstName|LastName         |Phone|Email       |
    |Gemunu   |Priyadarshana    |119  |abc@test.com|

* Fill Mailing Information section
    |Address1|Address2   |City  |State/Province|PostCode|Country    |
    |151     |Isadin Town|Matara|Southern      |82600   |SRI LANKA  |

* Submit user registration form
```

Please refer the following example. 
https://github.com/gemunulk/gauge-java-maven-selenium-page-factory-extended/blob/master/specs/concepts/user_reg.cpt